# Intel TBB Code having different execution time in windows and linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, tbb

I am trying to parallelize my code which is designing FIR Filter.For that i have chosen parallel_reduce .when i am executing code on windows it takes 15s and the same code when i am executing on linux it takes almost 2.5secs.In windows i am executing code on VS 2010 with Intel Performance libraries TBB Enabled and in linux i am compiling through terminal by including TBB libraries along with g++ compiler.
As processor is same and code also will execute on same processor why this OS makes difference?

Code which i have used is :

```
#include<iostream> 
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h" 
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h" 
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h" 
#include "tbb/compat/thread" 
#include "tbb/parallel_reduce.h" 
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace tbb; 
using namespace std; 

#define pi 3.141593
#define FILTER_LEN 265

double coeffs[ FILTER_LEN ] =
{
  0.0033473431384214393,0.000032074683390218124,0.0033131082058404943,0.0024777666109278788,
  -0.0008968429179843104,-0.0031973449396977684,-0.003430943381749411,-0.0029796565504781646,
  -0.002770673157048994,-0.0022783059845596586,-0.0008531818129514857,0.001115432556294998,
  0.0026079871108133294,0.003012423848769931,0.002461420635709332,0.0014154004589753215,
  0.00025190669718400967,-0.0007608257014963959,-0.0013703600874774068,-0.0014133823230551277,
  -0.0009759556503342884,-0.00039687498737139273,-0.00007527524701314324,-0.00024181463305012626,
  -0.0008521761947454302,-0.00162618205097997,-0.002170446498273018,-0.002129903305507943,
  -0.001333859049002249,0.00010700092934983156,0.0018039564602637683,0.0032107930896349583,
  0.0038325849735515363,0.003416201274366522,0.002060848732332109,0.00017954815260431595,
  -0.0016358832300944531,-0.0028402136847527387,-0.0031256650498727384,-0.0025374271571154713,
  -0.001438370315670195,-0.00035115295209013755,0.0002606730012030533,0.0001969569787142967,
  -0.00039635535951198597,-0.0010886127490608972,-0.0013530057243606405,-0.0008123200399262436,
  0.0005730271959526784,0.0024419465938120906,0.004133717273258681,0.0049402122577746265,
  0.0043879285604252714,0.002449549610687005,-0.00040283102645093463,-0.003337730734820209,
  -0.0054508346511294775,-0.006093057767824609,-0.005117609782189977,-0.0029293645861970417,
  -0.0003251033117661085,0.0018074390555649442,0.0028351284091668164,0.002623563404428517,
  0.0015692864792199496,0.0004127664681096788,-0.00009249878881824428,0.0004690173244168184,
  0.001964334172374759,0.0037256715492873485,0.004809640399145206,0.004395274594482053,
  0.0021650921193604,-0.0014888595443799124,-0.005534807968511709,-0.008642334104607624,
  -0.009668950651149259,-0.008104732391434574,-0.004299972815463919,0.0006184612821881392,
  0.005136551428636121,0.007907786753766152,0.008241212326068366,0.00634786595941524,
  0.003235610213062744,0.00028882736660937287,-0.001320994685952108,-0.0011237433853145615,
  0.00044213409507615003,0.0022057106517524255,0.00277593527678719,0.0011909915058737617,
  -0.0025807757230413447,-0.007497632882437637,-0.011739520895818884,-0.013377018279057393,
  -0.011166543231844196,-0.005133056165990026,0.0032948631959114935,0.011673660427968408,
  0.017376415708412904,0.018548938130314566,0.014811760899506572,0.007450782505155853,
  -0.001019540069785369,-0.007805775815783898,-0.010898333714715424,-0.00985364043415772,
  -0.005988406030111452,-0.001818560524968024,0.000028552677472614846,-0.0019938756495376363,
  -0.007477684025727061,-0.013989430449615033,-0.017870518868849213,-0.015639422062597726,
  -0.005624959109456065,0.010993528170353541,0.03001263681283932,0.04527492462846608,
  0.050581340787164114,0.041949186532860346,0.019360612460662185,-0.012644336735920483,
  -0.0458782599058412,-0.07073838953156347,-0.0791205623455818,-0.06709535677423759,
  -0.03644544574795176,0.005505370370858695,0.04780486657828151,0.07898800597378192,
  0.0904453420042807,0.07898800597378192,0.04780486657828151,0.005505370370858695,
  -0.03644544574795176,-0.06709535677423759,-0.0791205623455818,-0.07073838953156347,
  -0.0458782599058412,-0.012644336735920483,0.019360612460662185,0.041949186532860346,
  0.050581340787164114,0.04527492462846608,0.03001263681283932,0.010993528170353541,
  -0.005624959109456065,-0.015639422062597726,-0.017870518868849213,-0.013989430449615033,
  -0.007477684025727061,-0.0019938756495376363,0.000028552677472614846,-0.001818560524968024,
  -0.005988406030111452,-0.00985364043415772,-0.010898333714715424,-0.007805775815783898,
  -0.001019540069785369,0.007450782505155853,0.014811760899506572,0.018548938130314566,
  0.017376415708412904,0.011673660427968408,0.0032948631959114935,-0.005133056165990026,
  -0.011166543231844196,-0.013377018279057393,-0.011739520895818884,-0.007497632882437637,
  -0.0025807757230413447,0.0011909915058737617,0.00277593527678719,0.0022057106517524255,
  0.00044213409507615003,-0.0011237433853145615,-0.001320994685952108,0.00028882736660937287,
  0.003235610213062744,0.00634786595941524,0.008241212326068366,0.007907786753766152,
  0.005136551428636121,0.0006184612821881392,-0.004299972815463919,-0.008104732391434574,
  -0.009668950651149259,-0.008642334104607624,-0.005534807968511709,-0.0014888595443799124,
  0.0021650921193604,0.004395274594482053,0.004809640399145206,0.0037256715492873485,
  0.001964334172374759,0.0004690173244168184,-0.00009249878881824428,0.0004127664681096788,
  0.0015692864792199496,0.002623563404428517,0.0028351284091668164,0.0018074390555649442,
  -0.0003251033117661085,-0.0029293645861970417,-0.005117609782189977,-0.006093057767824609,
  -0.0054508346511294775,-0.003337730734820209,-0.00040283102645093463,0.002449549610687005,
  0.0043879285604252714,0.0049402122577746265,0.004133717273258681,0.0024419465938120906,
  0.0005730271959526784,-0.0008123200399262436,-0.0013530057243606405,-0.0010886127490608972,
  -0.00039635535951198597,0.0001969569787142967,0.0002606730012030533,-0.00035115295209013755,
  -0.001438370315670195,-0.0025374271571154713,-0.0031256650498727384,-0.0028402136847527387,
  -0.0016358832300944531,0.00017954815260431595,0.002060848732332109,0.003416201274366522,
  0.0038325849735515363,0.0032107930896349583,0.0018039564602637683,0.00010700092934983156,
  -0.001333859049002249,-0.002129903305507943,-0.002170446498273018,-0.00162618205097997,
  -0.0008521761947454302,-0.00024181463305012626,-0.00007527524701314324,-0.00039687498737139273,
  -0.0009759556503342884,-0.0014133823230551277,-0.0013703600874774068,-0.0007608257014963959,
  0.00025190669718400967,0.0014154004589753215,0.002461420635709332,0.003012423848769931,
  0.0026079871108133294,0.001115432556294998,-0.0008531818129514857,-0.0022783059845596586,
  -0.002770673157048994,-0.0029796565504781646,-0.003430943381749411,-0.0031973449396977684,
  -0.0008968429179843104,0.0024777666109278788,0.0033131082058404943,0.000032074683390218124,
  0.0033473431384214393
};



class SumFoo 
{ 
    double* my_a; 

    public: 
    double sum; 
        static int count;
        int ip,nip;
    void operator( )( const blocked_range<size_t>& r ) 
    { 
        double *a = my_a; 
       //   cout<<"id of thread is \t"<<this_thread::get_id()<<endl; 
        // cout<<"r.begin is "<<r.begin()<<"\t r.end is "<<r.end()<<endl; 
        ip=( FILTER_LEN - 1 + (SumFoo::count));
        for( size_t k=r.begin(); k!=r.end( ); ++k ) 
        {           
            nip=ip-k;
            sum+= ((coeffs[k]) * (a[nip]));                                       
         }
    }  

    SumFoo( SumFoo& x, split ) : my_a(x.my_a), sum(0) 
    { 
        //cout<<"split Constructor called"<<endl; 
    } 

    void join( const SumFoo& y ) 
    { 
        // cout<<"Joining all the sums"<<endl; 
        sum+=y.sum; 
    } 

    SumFoo(double a[] ) :my_a(a), sum(0) 
    { 
            // cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl; 
    } 
}; 

void ParallelSumFoo(double *a, size_t n ,ofstream &o) 
{ 
        SumFoo sf(a); 
        for(int j=264;j<150264;j++)
        {
                SumFoo::count=j-264;
                parallel_reduce(blocked_range<size_t>(0,265), sf,auto_partitioner() ); 
              o<<j<<","<<sf.sum<<endl;
        }

} 

int SumFoo::count=0;

int main() 
{ 

     ofstream o("400hzreduce.csv");

    double *buffer=new double[150264];  
    fill_n(buffer,150264,0);

    tick_count t0=tick_count::now(); 
    for(int i=264;i<150264;i++) 
    { 
        buffer[i] = sin(400 * (2 * pi) * (i / 5000.0));
        o<<i<<","<<buffer[i]<<endl;
    } 


    cout<<fixed; 


    ParallelSumFoo(buffer,150264,o);
    tick_count t1=tick_count::now(); 

    double t9=(t1-t0).seconds(); 
    cout<<"Time Taken for parallel execution is \t"<<t9<<"seconds"<<endl; 

}
```

Please help in finding where i am getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have similar compiler optimisation options on both OS dont you? -O3 Vs. nothing with gcc can make that sort of difference. With visual studio I'm not so sure of the options, but I'm sure you can hunt through the GUI and find them.

What is your run time on both systems without parallel_reduce? That will take 1 level of complexity away.

Have you tried profiling your code? I recommend `valgrind --tool=callgrind` and kcachegrind to view the results in Linux. This should help narrow down people responses.

Comment: yeah without parallel_reduce there is also a huge mismatch .for windows its taking 5.52sec and for linux its just 1.252252 sec.I don't have any idea of this tools please suggest how it can help me .

Comment: For the clarity of such test you could also run *CodeAnalyst* Performance Analyzer (http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/) which is available for free for both - Windows(AMD and Intel with limitations) and Linux (AMD processors only).

Comment: @Jasdeep Singh Arora, you haven't yet updated the question with the optmization flags ( build settings on both environments ). On Windows are you using VS ? If yes, which version and what are the settings ? Same goes with Linux as well.

Comment: If it goes faster without threading that often means you dont have enough work for each task. There can be other reasons, but this is what my money is on in this case.

Comment: By the way, the code might run faster if ip and nip are changed to local variables instead of member variables.  Compilers are much smarter about analyzing local variables than they are about structure fields.  For the same reason, consider using a local variable for sum while inside the loop, say "s".  If you make that change, be sure to load s from sum before the loop and store s into sum after the loop.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison i tried making nip and ip local inside operator and it lead to increased execution time. Reason i guess is declaration cost it has to pay everytime. similar is the case with s.

Comment: Declaration of an local integer variable should have zero cost if the code is compiled with with /O or -O.

Answer (score 0):

In this code , data is being written to file which makes a huge difference in execution time.Time taken for writing data to file is different in linux as windows , that is why time is different otherwise TBB does not makes any difference.